# SQL/PHP - On key update

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have messed up my database design a bit. This was the original schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xeon_stats_clicks` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `typ` enum('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `data` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `typ` (`typ`,`user`,`data`),
  KEY `data` (`data`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

As you can see, I have KEY on the following:

```
UNIQUE KEY `typ` (`typ`,`user`,`data`),
      KEY `data` (`data`)
```

I have the following code execute:

```
"INSERT INTO `xeon_stats_clicks` (typ, user, data, value) VALUES ('1', :username, :date, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = value + 1"
```

However, above code doesn't work now, as my table schema now look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `xeon_stats_clicks` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `typ` enum('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `user` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `data` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `value` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `idx_value` (`value`),
 KEY `idx_typ` (`typ`),
 KEY `idx_data` (`data`),
 KEY `idx_user` (`user`),
 KEY `data` (`data`),
 KEY `data_2` (`data`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=991799 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

How can I revert the changes made, and return to the first schema without messing up the data in the table?

Comment: why do you need two identical keys `KEY \`data\` (\`data\`), KEY \`data_2\` (\`data\`)`?

Comment: @Alex that was an error..

Comment: check last update in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why your first schema + code doesn't work.

It works for `value` that is `integer`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3260/1

```
INSERT INTO `xeon_stats_clicks` (typ, user, data, value) VALUES 
('2', 'user2', 'data3', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = `value` + 1
```

But if you will try on fiddle to apply that query to other lines it doesn't work. Because mysql can't convert `VARCHAR` to `INT`.

My guess you have wrong data in `value` column. For the combination of `(typ, user, data, value)` that you test.

**UPDATE** Here is the fiddle with your second schema in use:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ea62b/1

As you can see your query works fine as well if you add

```
UNIQUE KEY `typ` (`typ`,`user`,`data`),
```

to that second schema.

and here is `ALTER TABLE` variant that works as well:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57b409/1

**UPDATE 2** Another guess: You have broken uniqueness in your table now.

If I got you correctly you had

```
 UNIQUE KEY `typ` (`typ`,`user`,`data`),
```

when start the project. After a while you did remove that `UNIQUE KEY` from schema. That change allowed mysql to insert duplicate records into that table. And apparently you inserted several (or a lot) of duplicates. And now you want to apply `ALTER TABLE` to get back unique key but mysql refuse that because of that.

Like here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cbb5  <-- uncomment `ALTER` line to see error message

So you need to fix uniqueness first.

**UPDATE 3** Delete duplicates:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85f228/1

```
DELETE FROM xeon_stats_clicks USING xeon_stats_clicks
INNER JOIN xeon_stats_clicks dup
ON xeon_stats_clicks.id < dup.id
    AND xeon_stats_clicks.typ = dup.typ
    AND xeon_stats_clicks.user = dup.user
    AND xeon_stats_clicks.data = dup.data;
```

Comment: The first schema do work. But I messed up and altered the table to look like the 2nd schema. I just want my table to look like the first schema again..

Comment: so just add `UNIQUE KEY \`typ\` (\`typ\`,\`user\`,\`data\`),` to second schema

Comment: I tried. I did this ALTER TABLE xeon_stats_clicks ADD UNIQUE KEY `typ` (typ,user,data) - which gave me this error:  #1061 - Duplicate key name 'typ'

Comment: I can't reproduce your issues http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57b409  Probably ypou already applied `ALTER` once? Or maybe you use different databases. Do you have several test databases in use?

Comment: I was editing/altering the table from the old schema to the new, while data was being added from my php script. Meaning 290k rows can be inserted, but all rows after I changed it (the last 10K) cannot be inserted..

Comment: WHAT?!  I can not understand what you are talking about. Try to explain in your OP deeply with samples of data probably?

Comment: But how do I fix uniqueness? Your guess at what happened is spot on.